# Change type of extended entity field

Tags: orocrm

I have a custom field of type `Integer` in an entity, but unfortunatly, i need to change it to `BigInt`, is there an API function or a possibility of creating a migration to perform this ?

Bonus question: If not, how to delete an extended field ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a schema migration like that:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
//...
$schema
    ->getTable('your_entity_table_name')
    ->changeColumn('your_column_name', ['type' => Type::getType('bigint')]);
```

Comment: Is it the same to delete a column created in the entity manager ?

Comment: If you want to delete a column, you should use $table->dropColumn() to remove a column from a database and RemoveFieldQuery to remove column metadata from the database. For example, see how we deleted the address field in a lead entity https://github.com/oroinc/crm/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/SalesBundle/Migrations/Schema/v1_37/RemoveDeprecatedTablesAndFields.php#L20 and https://github.com/oroinc/crm/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/SalesBundle/Migrations/Schema/v1_37/RemoveDeprecatedTablesAndFields.php#L26-L29